# external static library

Tags: c++, qt, external

The library is called mod.lib, I have used the following lines to link the library. I also include its header file. Not sure what is wrong, but it kept giving me the undefined reference errors of library's functions when I try to use them in the code.

```
win32: CONFIG (release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/Users/J/proj -lmod
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/J/proj
DEPENDPATH += C:/Users/J/proj
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/Users/J/proj/mod.lib
```

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
LIBS += -L/C:/Users/J/proj -lmod
```

Instead of

```
LIBS += -LC:/Users/J/proj -lmod
```

The proper way for adding a library is

```
LIBS += -L/path/to -lyourmodule
```

Comment: Does the -L/path/to/something adds the path /path/to/something? In that case would -LC:/path/to/something add the path to C:/path/to/something and you are wrong, aren't you?